# jqgrid: how to use searchfunction?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jqgrid

I am trying to create an alfabetic index to quickly search for records in my jqGrid.

So for letter A it is:

```
 $("#Aletter").click(
                function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("Products")',
                type:'POST',
                data: '_search=true&nd=1345519741915&rows=10&page=1&sidx=ProductID&sord=asc&filters=%7B%22groupOp%22%3A%22AND%22%2C%22rules%22%3A%5B%7B%22field%22%3A%22ProductName%22%2C%22op%22%3A%22bw%22%2C%22data%22%3A%22a%22%7D%5D%7D&searchField=&searchString=&searchOper='
            });
        });
```

In fiddler it returns the right data.

The only problem is how to get it into the grid?

Comment: probably you are using addJSONData in wrong way, check this link http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/help/addjsondata-help/ and this link http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/help/help-needed-with-addjsondata-method/  are you sure you are getting response back as json?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.addJSONData(data);` method in your ajax `success` method.

```
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("Products")',
            type:'POST',
            data: '_search=...',
            success: function(data){
                 $("gridId").addJSONData(data);
            }
        });
```

See the [jqgrid wiki](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3amethods).

Comment: I am getting an error: TypeError: $("#jqgProducts").addJSONData is not a function?